# Isotope: Display More Filters When A Filter Is Selected

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to make my Isotope filter list more user friendly by hiding filters until something is selected.

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LxNXM/

I had trouble getting the Isotope to work in the JSFIddle, but hopefully I can get still get the needed help.

In the Fiddle, there is a thick green line.  Below that line are the filter options I would like to be hidden unless a "Body Part" is selected.

So if the filters below the green line are hidden, and a user selects "Chest" under Body Part, the "Chest" filters will fade in then the user can select Upper,Middle, or Lower.

I haven't seen this covered in the Isotope documentation how could I do this?

Got it to work like this:

1. added a ID around each bodypart focus filter list, example: #chestfocus
2. added an id to each anchor in the body part filter list, example: #chestclick

And here is the javascript that hides and displays the content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Hiding Focus Areas
    $('#chestfocus, #backfocus, #shouldersfocus, #legsfocus, #armsfocus').hide();


//Display Chest Focus List
    $("#chestclick").click(function() {
        $("#backfocus, #shouldersfocus, #legsfocus, #armsfocus").fadeOut("300", function(){
            $("#chestfocus").fadeIn("500");
        });
    });

//Display Back Focus List
    $("#backclick").click(function() {
        $("#chestocus, #shouldersfocus, #legsfocus, #armsfocus").fadeOut("300", function(){
            $("#backfocus").fadeIn("500");
        });
    });

//Display Shoulder Focus List
    $("#shouldersclick").click(function() {
        $("#backfocus, #chestfocus, #legsfocus, #armsfocus").fadeOut("300", function(){
            $("#shouldersfocus").fadeIn("500");
        });
    });

//Display Legs Focus List
    $("#legsclick").click(function() {
        $("#backfocus, #shouldersfocus, #chestfocus, #armsfocus").fadeOut("300", function(){
            $("#legsfocus").fadeIn("500");
        });
    });

//Display Arms Focus List
    $("#armsclick").click(function() {
        $("#backfocus, #shouldersfocus, #legsfocus, #chestfocus").fadeOut("300", function(){
            $("#armsfocus").fadeIn("500");
        });
    });
});
```

It kinda flashes the list before switching, is there a way to make the transition a little smoother?

Comment: That's not an Isotope issue; you can .hide() these filter divs and then .show() them when appropriate with some conditional logic.

Comment: @Systembolaget thanks for the direction! I edited the main post with the solution i came up with, does this seem like a good way to do this?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing it working online or as jsfiddle. But, your code has much redundancy. Why don't you just set up one generic click function for that part of your site and, depending on which "button" or div has been clicked, evaluate a HTML 5 data-attribute (head, shoulders, knees, toes, ...) associated with each different div? Data-attributes are useful to pass values into a function.